# "Follow curve" throws my objects chaotically

Tags: interface

Whenever I add the Follow Path constraint to an object, that object is thrown far away from where it was.

In this example, I have a camera I want to attach to the outermost circular path:
[image: image 1]

As soon as I add the Follow Path constraint and set it to follow the circle, the camera is moved far away:

[image: image 2]

No matter what kind of object I use or how I configure my circle, the object is always thrown wildly.

These are my settings:

[image: settings]

If I turn "Follow Curve" on, the camera is thrown to a different location. "Fixed Position" throws it to yet another location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I was typing this question, I figured out the answer. I needed to set the origin of my object to match the origin of my path.

Comment: The real issue is that the object and the curve **must have their origins in the same place**. In this case it's at 0,0,0 but if the curve's origin was elsewhere clearing the camera's location wouldn't work.

Comment: I updated my answer, in case anyone else finds this. Thanks!

Comment: I think there is a hidden X,Y,Z offset that gets initialized from the object's position when a constraint is added. That would explain the unexpected teleportation that happens most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a Follow Path Constraint, check if Camera has a parent.

ie:

[image]

In this case, clear Parent (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>) and clear Location (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>)